# Image Asset Not Loading In Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm running Rails 5.2.2. I recently separated some admin code from my frontend and in the process moved my controllers, views, css & JS to folders in either `frontend` or `admin` respectively.

In development, everything works fine. In production, I am unable to load image assets from my `css.scss` files using the following line `background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat left center;` (located in `app/assets/stylesheets/frontend/application.css.scss`).

My assets has the following file structure:

```
assets/
  config/
  images/ 
      admin/
      frontend/
      products/
      another_folder/
  javascripts/
      admin/
      frontend/
  stylesheets/
      admin/
      frontend/
```

I did not have to change any of my image tags in my views once I made these changes for my images in `assets/images/products` so I figured that I wouldn't have to do that anywhere else either; things just seemed to work. However, in production the `arrow.png` returns a `404`. When I inspect the image request, the link to the image is `/assets/frontend/arrow.png`. I use the `RAILS_ENV=production` flag when compiling assets. I have also run `rake assets:clobber` with the production flag then tried compiling the assets again. I've deleted all browsing data.

Here are my server logs where the image is requested:

```
I, [2019-08-01T05:06:22.496953 #6733] INFO -- : [8a0b82c0-c4a3-419f-92fd-8f4a89bbe643] Started GET "/assets/frontend/arrow.png" for 35.188.197.210 at 2019-08-01 05:06:22 +0000
F, [2019-08-01T05:06:22.501395 #6733] FATAL -- : [8a0b82c0-c4a3-419f-92fd-8f4a89bbe643] 
F, [2019-08-01T05:06:22.503739 #6733] FATAL -- : [8a0b82c0-c4a3-419f-92fd-8f4a89bbe643] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/frontend/arrow.png"):
```

UPDATE:

Adding this to a view works fine in production so I can confirm the asset does indeed compile properly.

```
 <%= image_tag("frontend/arrow.png") %>
```

Comment: did you try adding `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets")`  in your initializers/production.rb

Comment: I have not, but I thought that was the default behavior. I am able to verify that when I compile the assets in production the `arrow.png` file is generated in `/public/assets/frontend` with a hash. @AbhishekAravindan

Comment: `background: url(arrow.png)` server looks for the image in root path might be, check your server log

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan I've added the server log to the question.

Comment: its /assets/frontend/arrow.png , it should be `assets/images/frontend/arrow.png`

Comment: That's how I have it structured in my asset pipeline. The request in development that works is making a request to the same folder location.@AbhishekAravindan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197317/discussion-between-cannon-moyer-and-abhishek-aravindan).

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5, please try to change following configuration:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

to

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

OR

you can set `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true` in your passenger_env_var. That will also work.

Comment: This did not work. The rest of my assets render fine, it's just when I call an asset from the css.scss files.

Answer (score 0):

Helo is this code works for you?

```
background: image-url(arrow.png) no-repeat left center;
```

Comment: No, I received this error: `Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...image-url(arrow": expected ")", was ".png) no-repeat..."`